# Godot 4, 4 direction tile base movment

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

Hey i try to find best mechanics for movment like c64 BulderDash or Supaplex. I have couple versions for tilebase movment Characterbody2d with snap or Area2d with raycast.

If i use Characterbody2d even with snap still i cant figur how to block another direction movment before player go to specyfic tile and even i use if, elif still im able to change buttons quick and to between tiles.

If i use tween for moving it looks not natural even it will finish at good tile position.

If i use Area2d also im able to quick press buttons and move is not in tile lines.

```
extends Area2D

var tile_size = Vector2(32,32)

@onready var raycast = $RayCast2d

func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    
    var raycast = $RayCast2D
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
            $RayCast2D.target_position = $AnimatedSprite2D.position + Vector2(-32,0)
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("runing")
            $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = false
            if !raycast.is_colliding():
                position += Vector2(-32,0)
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
            $RayCast2D.target_position = $AnimatedSprite2D.position + Vector2(32,0)
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("runing")
            $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = true
            if !raycast.is_colliding():
                position += Vector2(32,0)
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
            $RayCast2D.target_position = $AnimatedSprite2D.position + Vector2(0,-32)
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("runing")
            if !raycast.is_colliding():
                position += Vector2(0,-32)
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
            $RayCast2D.target_position = $AnimatedSprite2D.position + Vector2(0,32)
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("runing")
            if !raycast.is_colliding():
                position += Vector2(0,32)
    else:
        $RayCast2D.target_position = $AnimatedSprite2D.position
        Vector2.ZERO
```

I have easy solution just change max FPS for 8-10 and then everything is working right, except ofc animations if they are preperred for more FPS

Maybe somebody will give me some good solution for that.

In engine like Construct everything is just 2 clicks but in Godot 4 is way harder than 3.5 or i just dont know right solution for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do for such cases is add a `busy` flag to the entity that gets set at the beginning of the animation and at the end is set back to `false`.
You may also want to add a buffer for inputs that happen during a step to execute them as soon as the entity is not `busy` anymore.